# Developing an SMS Sending Application using Java Swing

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a 2 functions in a class:

1. `login()` Logs into a site
2. `Send_Sms()` Sends the  sms

Here I am Thinking of putting 2 threads for the functions so that the exceution of the function `Send_Sms` can be controlled in a manner that it starts to send the sms after the `login()` has completed successfully otherwise program will not work.

This is what I have done so far :

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class RunThreads extends Thread
{
    public void Login(String username,String password)
    {
        try
        {
            // creates the batch file for Logging into abc.com server
            Writer output = null;
            String UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1;KM:10.0.2)";
            String postdata = "\"" + "username="+username+ "&password=" + password + "&button=Login" + "\"";
            String MainStream = "c:\\wget.exe --output-document=login.html --user-agent=" + "\"" + UserAgent + "\"" + " --max-redirect=10 --cookies=on --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies=cookie.txt --post-data " + postdata + " http://www.abc.com/Login1.action;";
            File file = new File("login.bat");
            output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            output.write(MainStream);
            output.close();
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start login.bat");
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(Save_Credentials.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    public void SendSms(String mobno,String content) throws IOException
    {
                Writer output = null;
                String UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1;KM:10.0.2)";
                String MainStream = "c:\\wget.exe --output-document=quicksms.html --user-agent=" + "\"" + UserAgent + "\"" + " --referer=http://www.abc.com/jsp/SMS.jsp --cookies=on --keep-session-cookies --load-cookies=cookie.txt --save-cookies=cookie.txt --post-data "+"\""+"&HiddenAction=instantsms&catnamedis=Birthday&Action=gstahsbdf5346g&chkall=on&MobNo="+mobno+"&textArea="+content+"\""+" http://www.abc.com/quicksms.action;";
                File file = new File("SendSms.bat");
                output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
                output.write(MainStream);
                output.close();
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start SendSms.bat");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since an SMS cannot be sent if the login fails, as you yourself said:

> the exceution of the function Send_Sms can be controlled in a manner
>   that it starts to send the sms after the login() has completed
>   successfully otherwise program will not work.

then these two tasks are sequentially coupled, meaning that executing them in parallel on different threads is meaningless. Just execute them in a sequence on a single thread.